# How can numerator and denominator of any variable-containing algebraic irrational term be uniquely defined in general?

Tags: notation, definition, radicals

My question is for formulation or notation of numerators and denominators of variable-containing algebraic irrational terms ([radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_in_radicals)) in general.

I'm looking for formulations to talk about variable-containing algebraic irrational terms

- whose numerator and denominator don't contain the same factor (are coprime) and
- whose numerator doesn't contain a certain factor.

But can numerator and denominator of any given variable-containing algebraic irrational term be defined uniquely?

Is there a suitable normal form for variable-containing algebraic irrational terms in algebraic simplification?

Clearly, all terms with negative exponents must be transformed into terms with positive exponents.

A very very simple example:

$$-1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}}$$
$$=-1+\sqrt{1+\frac{\sqrt{1+x}}{\sqrt{1-x}}}$$
$$=-1+\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x}}{\sqrt{1-x}}}$$
$$=-1+\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x}}}{(1-x)^\frac{1}{4}}$$
$$=\frac{-(1-x)^\frac{1}{4}+\sqrt{\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x}}}{(1-x)^\frac{1}{4}}$$

I want to speak about equations of the form

$$A(x)=0,$$

wherein $A$ is an algebraic function (over $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{C}$ or over any other field). I want to formulate that I want to split the largest possible denominator by multiplication with it. But how can I express/formulate this if the terms "numerator" and "denominator" aren't defined uniquely for variable-containing algebraic irrational terms?

**Addition:**
A general algebraic irrational term has some analogies to a finite continued fraction. Can all finite continued fractions be transformed into an ordinary fraction? How can I formulate mathematically correct that the numerator and denominator of the resulting ordinary fraction should be coprime?

Comment: What is a "radical term"? Can you you give an example of $A(x)$? Is it like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2524956/question-related-to-the-simplification-of-a-nested-radical-sqrtn-frac-sqrt?rq=1)?

Comment: It seems like you intend "radical term" to mean something like "an expression involving $1$, $x$, $+$, $-$, multiplication, division, and square roots/$n$th roots (which?)". Is that right? It should be noted that this is crucially different to what most people mean by "algebraic term", by the Abel-Ruffini theorem.

Comment: Rationalizing the denominators is the most common practice: $$\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}} =\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}\frac{1-x}{1-x}} = \frac{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}{1-x}$$

Comment: Rationalizing denominators could perhaps result in a normal form, but it's not possible in my problem because it introduces a common factor for numerator and denominator.